# How to test a command line options parser using GTest

Tags: c++, parsing, googletest

I am developing a command line options processor for my app. I have decided to use GTest to test it. It's implementation has been shown below in brief:

```cpp
int main(int argv, char **argv)
{
    if (!ProcessOptions(argc, argv)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Some more code here
    
    return 0;
}

int ProcessOptions(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        CheckOption(argv[i]);

        CheckArgument();

        if (Success)
        {
            EnableOption();
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs as expected, but the problem is: I want to test this using GTest by supplying different options (valid and invalid) to it. The GTest manual reads:

> The `::testing::InitGoogleTest()` function parses the command line for
> googletest flags, and removes all recognized flags. This allows the
> user to control a test program's behavior via various flags, which
> we'll cover in the AdvancedGuide. You must call this function before
> calling `RUN_ALL_TESTS()`, or the flags won't be properly initialized.

But this way, I will be able to test just one sequence. I want to do this multiple times for different options. How do I do that?

Is there any better strategy to achieve this? Can I do this using test fixtures?

Comment: You would have more than one test. Some of them would pass valid options. Some of them would pass invalid options. What's the problem? Can you show us your test code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a [value-parameterized test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests)? They sound perfect for your situation:

> Value-parameterized tests allow you to test your code with different parameters without writing multiple copies of the same test. This is useful in a number of situations, for example:
>
> - You have a piece of code whose behavior is affected by one or more command-line flags.
> - You want to test different implementations of an OO interface.
> - You want to make sure your code performs correctly for various values of those flags.

You could write one or more test(s) which define the expected behaviour of the command line argument parser and then pass the command line flags down to it this way.

A full code example is shown in the link to the Google Test GitHub docs, but here's a quick outline:

- Create a test class inheriting `testing::TestWithParam<T>`.
- Use `TEST_P` and within it, the `GetParam()` method to access the parameter value.
- You can instantiate your tests with `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P`. Use the `testing::Values` method to supply values.